# how to convert imputed dosage files to plink format files

Tags: linux, installation, bioinformatics, genetics, vcf-variant-call-format

I am trying to convert imputed dosage file from michigan imputation server to plink files.
For this purpuse I am using a tool called dosageconvertor.
I tried to install it using the commands:

```
> git clone https://github.com/Santy-8128/DosageConvertor cd
> DosageConverter pip install cget --user module load
> cmake-3.8.1-gcc-4.8.5-zz55m7x ./install.sh
```

But I am getting error:

> -- Build files have been written to: /home/scratch/TWAS/data_download/new_rna-seq/quality_Control/qc_vcf_impute/DosageConvertor/release-build
> Building ... make: Warning: File 'Makefile' has modification time 3675
> s in the future make[1]: Warning: File 'CMakeFiles/Makefile2' has
> modification time 3675 s in the future make[2]: Warning: File
> 'CMakeFiles/DosageConvertor.dir/flags.make' has modification time 3675
> s in the future Scanning dependencies of target DosageConvertor
> make[2]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
> make[2]: Warning: File 'CMakeFiles/DosageConvertor.dir/flags.make' has
> modification time 3675 s in the future [ 33%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/DosageConvertor.dir/src/HaplotypeSet.cpp.o [ 66%] Building
> CXX object CMakeFiles/DosageConvertor.dir/src/Main.cpp.o [100%]
> Linking CXX executable DosageConvertor
> /home/miniconda3/envs/train/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
> /home/miniconda3/envs/train/lib/libz.so: undefined reference
> to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14' /home/miniconda3/envs/train/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/miniconda3/envs/train/lib/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to` aligned_alloc@GLIBC_2.16'
> /home/miniconda3/envs/train/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
> /home/miniconda3/envs/train/lib/libstdc++.so: undefined
> reference to `clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17' collect2: error: ld returned 1
> exit status make[2]: ***
> [CMakeFiles/DosageConvertor.dir/build.make:101: DosageConvertor] Error
> 1 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73:
> CMakeFiles/DosageConvertor.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [Makefile:130:
> all] Error 2

Can anyone help me out with this?
My main purpose is to convert the dose.vcf.gz file to vcf format or plink format files.

Comment: Output from MIS is a vcf file, we can use vcf as an input for plink, no need for conversion.